# Does when configuring a new Google Analytics account from the old impact search engine optimization?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

The current Google Analytics account had been set-up by another party and we are looking at bringing this in-house. Losing historical data isn't a concern since this can be exported and referenced via other tool sets such as Microsoft Excel.

There is however a concern whether the set-up of a new account account with a new tracking ID will impact the current SEO standing.

Will this also require the set-up and configuration of the new webmaster tools?

Are there any considerations that need to taken on-board when undertaking this exercise?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics has no effect on SEO at all, as confirmed by Google multiple times ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgBw9tbAQhU)).

Regarding Webmaster Tools: if you set up a new GA account then yes, you will need to link the new account with your existing GWT account if you have one. As far as I know there are no ramifications from doing this.

Comment: Thanks. When you say `you may even have historical GWT data in your GA account`, do you mean to say there is the ability to migrate the `old` GWT data to the `new`? If so, is there a resource that outlines the process?

Comment: When you link GWT and GA, Analytics has a page for search queries that takes data from your GWT account. If your GWT account is, say, 2 years old, GA can see all that data. So it should show it in your GA account (but I don't know for definite, sorry).

Comment: Apologies. I don't quite follow since the `new` GWT account has yet to be set-up. I would imagine that the `new` analytic account would need to be linked with the `new` GWT account and not the old.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. If you don't already have a GWT account then ignore that part.